# What part of the sitecore PAAS setup is using redis?

Tags: session-state, performance, redis

We're using Sitecore 9.1 and are having some issues with our session management.
After changing it from Redis to InProc (both session-state and shared session-state), the issues disappeared.

What surprised us is that we saw that the load on the Redis server didn't go away. It stayed the same at about 400-500 gets/sets per second.
So my question is, where do these requests originate?
Is there another process using Redis?

Thanks for any insights provided.

Rik

Answer (score 2):

If you are on managed cloud (Azure Paas), these are the config files that are referencing Redis

1. App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config  ("redis.sessions")
2. App_Config\Sitecore\Azure\Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.Azure.config (patch:attribute name="defaultProvider" value="redis")
3. Web.config (sessionState configurations)

Make sure to remove these references from both **CM and CD app services**

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to make use of Redis cache, and you are getting timeout issues, have a look at this kb article: [Redis driver timeout issues](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/464570).

After applying the patch, I'd recommend you to do some load testing and fine tune the thread pool values until you find the ones that best fits your app.